# How to add style after add element in array?

Tags: angular

I have this in html :

```
  <ul class="operators">
            <li>Operators: </li>
            <li *ngFor="let operator of operators" [ngClass]="{'bold' :uS.getUserCode() == operator }"><i
                class="fa fa-at"></i>
              {{userService.getName(operator)}}</li>
          </ul>
```

On enter i insert in array opertaros new operator.

But i want to check if `uS.getUserCode() == operator` to add class 'bold'.
`uS.getUserCode()` is a `@Injectable()` service that is loaded on start of app and i imported it in constructor.

Any suggestion how can i achive this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue

Comment: What is `operator`? Also did you mean `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: operator is user code : string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `uS`is injected as public in constructor as

```
constructor(public uS: UsService) {}
```

this will let us us uS in view so you can check your condition in ngFor.

```
[ngClass]="{'bold': uS.getUserCode() === operator}"
```

i assume getUserCode() returns objects and you're comparing it to operator. It is suggested to be compared by some property in order to return true or false instead of comparing objects like this.